# How does Java bitwise shift code operation work in this code?

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, packet

So I have a code that creates a udp packet to be sent to a gateway device. The header of the packet is created according the following specifications:

[image]

And here is the Java code that creates it:

```
    private static final int CRC_SIZE = 2;
    private static final int HEADER_SIZE = 9;      
    private static final int GW_ADR_POS = 0;
    private static final int GW_ADR_VALUE = 0x22;

    private static final int CMD_POS = 1;
    private static final int CMD_WRITE_VALUE = 0x03;

    private static final int SUBCMD_POS = 2;
    private static final int SUBCMD_WRITE_VALUE = 0;

    private static final int DLEN_H_POS = 7;
    private static final int DLEN_L_POS = 8;


public static short[] transformRequestData(short[] data) {
        checkRequest(data);
        short[] transformedData = new short[HEADER_SIZE + data.length + CRC_SIZE];

        transformedData[GW_ADR_POS] = GW_ADR_VALUE;
        transformedData[CMD_POS] = CMD_WRITE_VALUE;
        transformedData[SUBCMD_POS] = SUBCMD_WRITE_VALUE;

        System.arraycopy(data, 0, transformedData, HEADER_SIZE, data.length);

        transformedData[DLEN_H_POS] = (short)((data.length & 0xFF00) >> 8);
        transformedData[DLEN_L_POS] = (short)(data.length & 0xFF);

        int crc = calculateCRC_microrisc(transformedData, 0, HEADER_SIZE + data.length);

        transformedData[HEADER_SIZE + data.length] = (short)((crc & 0xFF00) >> 8);
        transformedData[HEADER_SIZE + data.length+1] = (short)(crc & 0xFF);

        return transformedData;
    }
```

So basically what is happening is that the function transformRequestData takes a HEX string of data and prefixes the HEADER information and suffixes the CRC.

My problem is how do I set PACID_H and PACID_L in this code. When I read the UDP output, RES RES PACID_H PACID_L are all 0x00. In order for my gateway to read the packets properly, PACID_H and PACID_L should have set values that are not 0x00.
I believe it has something to do with the following code:

```
System.arraycopy(data, 0, transformedData, HEADER_SIZE, data.length);
transformedData[DLEN_H_POS] = (short)((data.length & 0xFF00) >> 8);
```

where there is some kind of bit shifting going on that pads RES RES PACID_H PACID_L with all zeroes and then continues to add the rest of the data.
I have tried to understand what the bitwise shift operation is doing but I have failed to grasp it.
How can I change this code so as to set PACID_H and PACID_L with random HEX values? (While leaving RES as is)?

Comment: Why are you using `short[]` to build a packet of *bytes*? Use a `byte[]`. --- You say *"function transformRequestData takes a HEX string of data"*, but it takes a `short[]`, which presumably is supposed to be a `byte[]`. Neither is a hex `String`.

Comment: You already know how to set an upper/lower pair of bytes, as exemplified with the DLEN bytes, so doing the same for PACID should be easy enough. Now, what the "packet identification" *value* is supposed to be, is up to you, according to that last part, it will be echoed back on the response for identification, so you decide.

Comment: For example, you want to set 0xABCD as your PACID. So the upper should be 0xAB, the lower should be 0xCD. The bit shifting will filter this value for you. First, 0xABCD & 0xFF00 => 0xAB00, then 0xAB00 >> 8 => 0x00AB. So, you can store it into your transformedData at the PACID_H position. The PACID_L should be the same but with lower filter just like `transformedData[DLEN_L_POS] = (short)(data.length & 0xFF);`